# How to create a redirect in PHP if the url is a specified?

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect localhost to my ip in one file. If I watch it with my IP don't redirect.
I have writed some code but don't work any.

```
<?php
//if $actual_link = 'localhost/docs/headertest.php' {
//header( 'Location: http://MYIP/docs/headertest.php' );};
//echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]<br>";
//echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
//echo "<br>";
//echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//if $actual_link =;
//if $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] = "/docs/headertest.php" {
//header( 'Location: http://MYIP/docs/headertest.php' )};
//$url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
//echo $url;
//if $url = "localhost/docs/headertest.php" {
//echo "asd";};
//header( 'Location: http://MYIP/docs/headertest.php' );};
$url = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; 
$localhost = "http://localhost/docs/headertest.php";
if $url = ($localhost){
header( 'Location: http://MYIP/docs/headertest.php' );}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out `$url` and `$localhost` to check they are matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; 
$localhost = "http://localhost/docs/headertest.php";
if ($url == $localhost){
header( 'Location: http://MYIP/docs/headertest.php' );
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to vote the answers you consider helpful!